# unable to open hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, ntfs

i install ubuntu few hour before, but i am unable to access hard drive. the message shown is given below-
Error mounting /dev/sda6 at /media/jeetu/24386BED386BBD04: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda6" "/media/jeetu/24386BED386BBD04"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda6': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.

Comment: Disable Hybrid Sleep in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

It's a common problem in computers with dual-boot with windows 8 (and 10 pheraps).
The problem is that when windows shuts down it does not "unmount" the disk correctly, it leaves it in a suspended state because the system does not really shut down, it hibernates.
The solution is to shut down windows properly, not hibernating.
You can achieve this by disabling hibernation, it will result in a slower startup of windows, but will not give any problem in Ubuntu.

To do this (assuming you have windows 8 or 8.1):
open **cmd.exe** as **administrator** (you can do that from the "metro home", then right click on "command prompt" and execute as administrator),
then type:

```
powercfg /h off
```

If you ever want to turn it back on you can simply type

```
powercfg /h on
```

on an administrator command prompt.

This will solve the problem, cheers!

Comment: after installing ubuntu window is never open . after click on window 8 loader option nothing happen, no warning, again options come ...

Comment: Have you installed grub-efi?

Comment: i'm not install

Comment: try this commands then:
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi` -
`sudo grub-install /dev/sdX`  - 
`sudo update-grub`

Comment: where X in sdX is the letter of your hard disk from which you're going to boot

Comment: if this doesn't work i suggest to open a new question, since this is a little off-topic relatively to the question subject